# How to install google-chrome as non-root user on a remote server?

Tags: linux, remote, testing, chrome, selenium

In order to use `google-chrome` for selenium-testing purposes (to be run headless of course) I want to install this on a remote server where I do not have root access. This server does not even have `dpkg` installed and uses `spack` as the package handler.

I found  [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198014/install-google-chrome-ubuntu-12-04-without-sudo) which unfortunately uses `dpkg` to install google-chrome.

Also, `spack` does not seem to list `google-chrome` or `chrome` as available software.

Maybe there is some other way I can try to install `google-chrome`, or there is some other way I can use a browser in the context of `py.test/selenium/python` tests?

Comment: aslong as your not root I guess that you not allowd to administrate the Server. Consider to contact the owner of the device to get the package

Comment: It looks like Chrome is only distributed as packages these days. You can probably install Chromium instead, which is available as a binary tarball that you should be able to use w/o root privileges, and both Selenium and Playwright should support Chromium.